# desktop right click options missing and can't able to add shortcuts

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, desktop-icons

**when I right click on desktop there is only three options showing**

- change background
- display settings
- settings

**ohter options like**

- new folder
- paste
- undo
- open in terminal

**are not showing**

[right click menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGBZV.jpg)

**And also I can't able to add any shortcut to desktop**

[shortcut not showing screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KWRQ.jpg)

**I think my desktop folder and actual desktop is not in sync**

**Because i pasted one file in desktop folder but the file is not in starting window desktop**

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate which version/distro of Ubuntu you are using.